# Finding Min and Max values from each column

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to find the min and max values of each column in a matrix, but my current code isn't running correctly. I am trying to put the min values in the first row of a new matrix and the max in the next row and do this for each column. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
public double[][] findMinMaxValuesOfEachColumn(double[][] customerBehaviorMatrix) {
       double[][] minMaxValuesMatrix = new double[2][customerBehaviorMatrix[0].length];
    //assign min and max values to return matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < minMaxValuesMatrix[0].length; j++) {
        minMaxValuesMatrix[0][j] = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        minMaxValuesMatrix[1][j] = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    //for each column find min and max
    //[0][]=min and [1][]=max
    for (int i = 0; i < customerBehaviorMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < customerBehaviorMatrix[i].length; j++) {                                
            //check min
            if (customerBehaviorMatrix[i][j] < minMaxValuesMatrix[0][j]) {
                //store min in the return matrix
                minMaxValuesMatrix[0][j] = customerBehaviorMatrix[i][j];
            }               
            //check max
            if (customerBehaviorMatrix[i][j] > minMaxValuesMatrix[1][j]) {
                //store max in the return matrix
                minMaxValuesMatrix[1][j] = customerBehaviorMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return minMaxValuesMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise than "isn't running correctly"?

Comment: So far rather than returning the expected min value from the matrix it has just been returning the Double.MIN_VALUE

Comment: When you use a debugger, why doesn't it change the min value when you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JUnit test for your method, and it passed.

```
@Test
public void calculatesMinAndMaxValuesForEachColumn() {
    double[][] matrix = {
        {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
        {4.0, 5.0, 6.0},
        {3.0, -2.0, 9.0}
    };

    double[][] minMaxMatrix = findMinMaxValuesOfEachColumn(matrix);

    double tolerance = 0.0001;

    double[] minValues = minMaxMatrix[0];
    assertEquals(1.0, minValues[0], tolerance);
    assertEquals(-2.0, minValues[1], tolerance);
    assertEquals(3.0, minValues[2], tolerance);

    double[] maxValues = minMaxMatrix[1];
    assertEquals(4.0, maxValues[0], tolerance);
    assertEquals(5.0, maxValues[1], tolerance);
    assertEquals(9.0, maxValues[2], tolerance);
}
```

If you can write a test that fails, then edit your post with the test, and we'll help debug it.